# BigQuery sum of data for events

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have table with events: event_name, datetime, proposal_id, customer_id.
I have many different events, but I am interested only in events (artifical names): A, B. Datetime of A is start, datetime of event B is stop. I need to calculate sum(stop - start) across each pair of A, B for proposal_id and then calculate average value. Might be multiple As and Bs, and those can interleave.

| event_name | datetime | proposal_id | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20210101 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 20210102 | 1 | 2 |
| B | 20210103 | 1 | 2 |
| B | 20210104 | 1 | 1 |

I have created following query, but seems to be too complicated:

```
select avg(followed_by) as average,
       proposal_id
from (
         select proposal_id,
                event_name,
                event_datetime,
                customer_id,
                cast(LEAD(event_datetime) over (partition by proposal_id) order by customer_id, event_datetime asc) as int64) 
              - cast(event_datetime as int64) as followed_by
              from events
              where event_name in ("A", "B"))
where event_name = "A"
group by proposal_id
```

Do you have maybe some ideas for cleaner solution?

Comment: And what if a given customer has multiple As and Bs?  What if they are interleaved?  Your question is not complete.  And why are you treating the `datetime` column as if it were an integer?

Comment: Yes, sorry, might be multiple As and Bs, might be interleaved. I got datatime column as string, I cast to int in order to substract days between. This is still draft version